# convert output of a query to json in oracle 12c

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have a query, the output is like this:

```
    1  2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13
    -  - - - - - - - - -   -  - -    
    40 20 22 10 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

I want to convert the output to one column and the column is like below:

```
    output
    -----------
 {"1":40,"2":20,"3":22,"4":10,"5":0,"6":0,"7":0,"8":0,"9":0,"10":0,"11":0,"12":0,"13":0}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want Oracle DB server to return the result as JSON, you can do query as below -

```
 SELECT JSON_OBJECT ('1' VALUE col1, '2' VALUE col2, '3' VALUE col3) FROM table
```

Comment: which SqlDeveloper version are you using?

Comment: Version 18.2.0.183

Comment: Can you try this way?

SELECT JSON_OBJECT ('1' VALUE col1, '2' VALUE col2, '3' VALUE col3) FROM table;

Comment: using the json comment, with f5, the resultset will be formatted as json client side when executed in SQL Developer - if you use json_object() the db will do the json-ification work

Comment: @shakhawat : SELECT JSON_OBJECT ('1' VALUE col1, '2' VALUE col2, '3' VALUE col3) FROM table; It works , thank you please edit your answer  and I accept your question as a correct answer

Comment: I am getting error 

`00907. 00000 -  "missing right parenthesis"
*Cause:    
*Action:
Error at Line: 30 Column: 30`

when running this statement: 

`SELECT JSON_OBJECT ('1' VALUE col1, '2' VALUE col2, '3' VALUE col3) FROM dual`

Answer (score 7):

You can use the JSON formatting 'trick' in SQL Developer.

[image]

Full scenario:

```
CREATE TABLE JSON_SO (
    "1"   INTEGER,
    "2"   INTEGER,
    "3"   INTEGER,
    "4"   INTEGER,
    "5"   INTEGER,
    "6"   INTEGER
);

INSERT INTO JSON_SO VALUES (
    40,
    20,
    22,
    10,
    0,
    0
);

select /*json*/ * from json_so;
```

And the output when executing with F5 (Execute as Script):

```
{
   "results":[
      {
         "columns":[
            {
               "name":"1",
               "type":"NUMBER"
            },
            {
               "name":"2",
               "type":"NUMBER"
            },
            {
               "name":"3",
               "type":"NUMBER"
            },
            {
               "name":"4",
               "type":"NUMBER"
            },
            {
               "name":"5",
               "type":"NUMBER"
            },
            {
               "name":"6",
               "type":"NUMBER"
            }
         ],
         "items":[
            {
               "1":40,
               "2":20,
               "3":22,
               "4":10,
               "5":0,
               "6":0
            }
         ]
      }
   ]
}
```

Note that the JSON output happens client-side via SQL Developer (this also works in SQLcl) and I formatted the JSON output for display here using https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/

This will work with any version of Oracle Database that SQL Developer supports, while the [JSON_OBJECT()](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/adjsn/generation.html#GUID-1084A518-A44A-4654-A796-C1DD4D8EC2AA) function was introduced in Oracle Database 12cR2 - if you want to have the DB format the result set to JSON for you.

Comment: you can also use SET SQLFORMAT json...or csv, insert, html, delimited, loader, xml